# cURL: multiple POST requests while reusing the TCP connection

Tags: linux, curl

If multiple URLs are passed to cURL, it reuses the TCP connection when possible.

For example:

```
curl -o 1.jpg http://example.com/1.jpg -o 2.jpg http://example.com/2.jpg
```

I need to do the same, but with different post queries to the same URL.

I thought maybe this would work:

```
curl -d "a=1" -o 1 http://example.com/script.php -d "a=2" -o 2 http://example.com/script.php
```

But instead of separating the `-d` arguments per request, it just adds them together.

Is there any way to achieve what I want with cURL?

If not, is there another tool which is likely to be present on a Linux system (e.g. Wget) which can do the above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since curl 7.36.0, the **`--next`** or **`-:`** command-line option allows delimiting URLs and their associated options. From the [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> For example, you can do both a GET and a POST in a single command
>   line:
>
> ```
> curl www1.example.com --next -d postthis www2.example.com
> ```

Your desired request could be:

```
curl -d "a=1" -o 1 http://example.com/script.php --next -d "a=2" -o 2 http://example.com/script.php
```

Comment: Great, thanks. [The relevant blog post](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2014/03/12/whats-next-for-curl/) which mentions persistent connection handling.

Answer (score 3):

[The answer](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-11/0013.html) of Daniel Stenberg, the author of cURL:

> We've previously discussed adding that ability but so far we haven't.

Comment: Why did you accept this answer, when it clearly doesn't actually answer the question?  Also, where's the reference?

Comment: That's the answer: it's not possible. Added a reference.

Comment: It is now possible from curl 7.36.0. See my own separate answer.